# MySQL: Select data from numerous sources, consolidate into one response - shopping cart migration

Tags: php, mysql

I'm really struggling on this. I'm migrating from one shopping cart CMS to another. I've got to move the past orders data. The database's are structured differently so I need to script the migration. The SQL query I'm coming up with is:

```
SELECT tblCustomers.*, tblAddress_Book.*,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(orders_id) FROM orders WHERE customers_id = tblCustomers.customers_id)
FROM customers as tblCustomers
JOIN address_book as tblAddress_Book
ON tblCustomers.customers_id = tblAddress_Book.customers_id
```

Ideally what I'm looking to do is to pull the data in a format as such

all columns from customer's table, all columns from address book in relation to customer's id, the orders made in relation to customer's id if exists, I need to join the data from orders table into one cell per customer id

I still want to grab the customers that didn't make orders as well.

I hope I explained that clearly enough. I've been searching and tinkering with it for hours but I'm not getting any closer. Hopefully someone can help

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` your orders table instead of making a subquery. It's more concise and will also make sure to select customers without previous orders.

Comment: `SELECT tblCustomers.*, tblAddress_Book.*, tblOrders.*, tblProducts.*
FROM customers as tblCustomers
JOIN address_book as tblAddress_Book
ON tblCustomers.customers_id = tblAddress_Book.customers_id
LEFT JOIN orders as tblOrders
ON tblCustomers.customers_id = tblOrders.customers_id
LEFT JOIN orders_products as tblProducts
ON tblOrders.orders_id = tblProducts.orders_id`

I think this will get the job done, thanks!

Comment: Showing sample data from `customers` and `address_book` would he helpful.